# Creating dataframes from a list of queries with a defined list of names

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to run a query which changes the name of different dataframes pulled from an SQL database. I have developed a simple definition to run the query given the name of the SQL file. the for loop is running properly but it will rewrite **Query** to the last observed dataframe from the report function.

```
def report(query_name):

   df = []

   filename = query_name +'.sql'

   # read the sql file 
   with open(filename, 'r') as query:

        
       connection = sql_server_connection(server = "server", database = "database")
       with connection:
            df = pd.read_sql_query(query.read(), connection)
  
   return df

queries = ['name1','name2','name3']

for query in queries:
    query = report(query)
```

What I wish to see from this is

name1 = data from report(name1)

name2 = data from report(name2)

name3 = data from report(name3)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about storing the DataFrames inside a `dict` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
queries = ['name1','name2','name3']
querie_data = {}

for query in queries:
    querie_data[query] = report(query)
```

To access the data

```
querie_data['name1']
```